# Can I Delete Specific Apps Through Terminal while booted to recovery or an os installer?

Tags: macos, terminal, recovery, catalina

I think I have a failed installation issue from trying to install Catalina. Apparently there wasn’t enough space, and when it restarted I wasn’t able to log into my MacBook. Every time I do, the progress bar goes halfway, and then the MacBook shuts down.

I’ve tried to use command + S boot up, but it just shows the login screen as usual. It doesn’t show the terminal, except when I shut it back down or restart (for a brief second).

This means I have to use recovery mode’s terminal. I need to use the terminal in recovery mode to delete my Adobe apps so I can free up space to reinstall Catalina from recovery mode. 
The problem is, when I navigate to cd /Applications, there’s nothing but Safari.app and Utilities. How do I find my Adobe apps?!

[image]

I ran ls in cd /Volumes, and it says:

```
Macintosh HD
Macintosh HD - Data
macOS Base System
```

Comment: best guess… from Recovery `/Applications` is looking at the wrong drive. Try `/Volumes/[Macintosh HD - Data]/Applications/` Double-check the drive name, Catalina renames them - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650

Comment: The `df` command needs to be run to show the mounted volumes. / is the installer that’s running and not your actual internal drive with your apps and your data.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371863/mac-stuck-in-restart-cycle-after-failed-macos-catalina-update?rq=1

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, and it told me it wasn’t a location.

Comment: What is the df command exactly? I used it to show what was taking the most space, but it still wouldn’t let me navigate to Macintosh HD - Data.

Comment: Please run `ls /Volumes` and add the result to the question

Comment: @nohillside updated the OP with that info

Comment: Try `cd /Volumes/M*Data`  then

Comment: @nohillside I got in, and have been able to start clearing space. Once I find my Adobe apps I should be in business. Thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 1):

Using the Terminal app. Look in /Volumes to see if the name of your normal desktop hard drive is there.

If so cd to /Volumes/< Insert your home volume name >/Applications

That will take you to the applications folder of your desktop.  Where you can remove unneeded items.

If not present, you will need to mount it.  If using a standard disk with a recovery volume you can issue the following command (with root permission)

```
mkdir /Volumes/mydrive
mount /dev/disk1s5 /Volumes/mydrive
cd /Volumes/mydrive
```

an "ls" should show you the Applications directory where you can remove the needed items.

Comment: Recovery has already mounted the volume in most cases.

Comment: @SamuraiJack42 Ok I was able to get to /Volumes, but if I cd /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Applications, it tell me no such file or directory. I imagine I haven’t typed the Macintosh HD - Data correctly?

Comment: @Eds94 Try `cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Applications"` (with the quotes).

Comment: @nohillside Thank you. I still got the no such file directory message though.