# Recover MacBook with full disk after failed OS upgrade

Tags: catalina, recovery, macos

I tried to install the latest MacOS and the installation failed because there was no enough space. From there on every time I try log in to my account a status bar appears and then the whole system shuts down. Same thing happens in Safe mode.

In recovery mode I tried a clean OS install but the wizard said that there is 0kB free on my disk. I imagine the installer from the previous upgrade attempt is still somewhere on my disk, taking up a lot of space.

So I tried launching a terminal and deleting random unneeded files.

After having deleted probably between 500 and 1000 MB of data, I tried restarting and logging in, but the system shuts down at the same point in that login status bar.

FileVault is enabled on my laptop.

How can I recover my laptop?

Comment: [Three main paths](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371863/) forward as I see it. How good and recent is your backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few good [suggestions here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371863/mac-stuck-in-restart-cycle-after-failed-macos-catalina-update). In the end the approach that solved my problem was starting recovery mode, and deleting a lot of unneeded files from my hard disk. 
(There was a lot of leftover stuff in `Library/Application Support` from applications that I have long ago uninstalled.)

After I freed up ~20GB of data, I could launch a reinstall of MacOS from recovery mode, which did the trick.